# Telerik:RadButton is not compatible with Internet Explorer 10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik

I am using .Net Framework version 4.5.50938 SP1. Internet Explorer 10.

Existing markup in .aspx page is following:

It works fine with IE 8. The problem is that it is not compatible with IE 10. When I click the Save button the button click event is not working. The Page is not navigating to anywhere- it stays stand still.

I tried to replace Telerik:RadButton with asp:Button, but it shows the following error: **ASP.NET runtime error: The base class includes the field 'SaveButton', but its type (Telerik.Web.UI.RadButton) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControl.Button).**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What document mode is the page on when you access it with IE10? (Press F12 to pull up the developer tools)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<html class=" _Telerik_IE9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: What version of Telerik controls are you using?

Comment: Telerik Version is 2011.3.1305.35

Comment: Do you get any script errors? That version should probably work with IE10 but still an old version so an upgrade might help.

Comment: Looks like an upgrade is the answer.. http://www.telerik.com/forums/getting-a-unable-to-get-property-documentelement-of-undefined-or-null-reference-error#PWLR8LQ0jkmNR_n7k15Lng

Comment: Please look at the document mode in the IE Developer tools, not the doc type in the HTML.

Comment: Standards mode is selected by default.
It lists the options of:
Quirks, IE9, IE8, IE7, IE5 Quirks.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, however, Upgrade is not possible currently. I tried using the javaScript patch you provided the link, still the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

That's an old version from before IE10 was out (**your 2011 version is good for up to IE9**), so it is likely that something will break. **Upgrading is the way to go**, as Mike said.

Another option to try is an X-UA Compatible meta tag, but I don't know if it will help much, because it is still not a real IE8/9 (whatever you put it into), but an IE10 with its own quirks, bugs and changes. Here is an example

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```